# Saving a JSON data from an Azure Function

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus, azure-blob-storage

I have integrated an **Azure Service Bus** and an **Azure Function** to receive a message, and then update a SQL DB.

I want to save a JSON created from a query from the same Database to a **Azure Blob**.

My questions are:

1. I can save the JSON by calling the Azure Blob REST API. Is it a Cloud Native pattern to call one service from another service?
2. Is sending the JSON to the **Azure Service Bus** and another **Azure Function** saving the data to the Blob an optimal approach?
3. Is a resource other than **Azure Blob** to save the JSON data from an **Azure Function** which will make the integration easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. There are many ways of saving a file in Azure Blob, if you want to save over HTTP, use Azure Blob REST API, you can also use Microsoft Azure Storage SDK that you can integrate into your application, there are storage client for many languages (.NET, Python, javascript, GO, etc.) or if you are using Azure function, you can use Output Binding.
2. it depends... Blob Storage is not the only location where you can save JSON, you can also save JSON straight into a SQL database for instance.
3. The easiest way to save from an Azure function is to use Azure Blob storage output binding for Azure Functions.